# piping grep to list files

Tags: linux, grep

Sample line in a file:

```
Populating response|boy|sessionType=Random
```

Sample line in another file :

```
Populating response|boyhood|sessionType=Random
```

There are several files in the directory with similar output.
I need to list all files which contain the line with boy(and not boyhood)

How do I list the files using grep (or any alternative).

`grep -l "Populating response.*boy" *.txt | grep -v "boyhood"` would obviously not work

Comment: fyi: `-l` option is used to get only filenames in output, so the `grep -v` you tried will be acting upon filenames, not the lines that matched...

Comment: since you have tagged linux, you probably have `GNU grep`... in which case adding word boundaries `\<boy\>` might help... though from given sample, using `|boy|` should work as well

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -inIEr 'boy' *.txt | grep -v hood
```

replace `*.txt` with file type

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep -lF '|boy|' *`

`-l` list only the files that matches.
`-F` search for the literal string `|boy|`.
`*` search all files in the current directory.

Comment: Exact literal wouldnt work - as |boy| is not the only key for the grep

Comment: @IUnknown I'm not sure if I understand. Do you mean there could be a file with `|boykott|` that should be listed? What about `|attaboy|`? Please make more examples in your question.

Comment: @IUnknown That did not help much. Please make a bigger list of examples, that is lines from files that should be listed and lines from files that should not be listed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
grep "boyhood" *.txt -vl | xargs grep "Populating response.*boy" -l
```

That'll first filter by eliminating the "boyhood" files and keeping only filenames.

Then for each result it'll parse it again and print them if matching.

Comment: This would need to parse the files again - is this the only option?